# Ember.TextField target the view from inside a component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a component that contains a view. This view uses the {{input}} helper to render an Ember.TextField.

I have an action defined on the child view (*not* the component), which needs to be triggered on the `escape-press` action emitted from the TextField. How do I target the current view using the {{input}} helper?

Here's a [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nedanego/1/edit) with the whole setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To tell a Component to send actions to a particular target object, set it's `targetObject` property:

```
{{input escape-press="alert" targetObject=view placeholder="Press <esc> when focused"}}
```

I've updated the [jsbin here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nedanego/3/edit) to show it working.

(Also, your original jsbin had a typo in the `WrapperView` - `action` instead of `actions`)

Comment: Thanks - that does seem to work. But doesn't that seem inconsistent with the rest of the actions API? Everywhere else I've seen, it's `target`. And looking through the code, it seems like targetObject is normally a computed property which checks the `target` value, but we are just clobbering that by overwriting the whole thing with a fixed value.

Comment: Yes, it does feel a little inconsistent. You're referring to the computed property definition [in TargetActionSupport](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages_es6/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/target_action_support.js#L32) that checks the `target` value. However, if you look at the definition of `Component` you'll see that `targetObject` is [overridden](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.5.0/packages/ember-views/lib/views/component.js#L184). It would seem more consistent if `Component` specified a computed `target` property instead of the seemingly private `targetObject`.